# How to bring a window to the top?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, modal-dialog, winapi

I created this code that brings Internet Explorer window to the top.

```
    public void avtivateIEWin(IntPtr win){
        int foregrRes = SetForegroundWindow(win);
        log("foregrRes:" + foregrRes);
        ShowWindowAsync(win, SW_SHOW);
        BringWindowToTop(win);
        SetActiveWindow(win);
        SwitchToThisWindow(win, true); 
        SetFocus(win);
```

}

(the purposes of my program is to emulate Alt-Tab behavior to switch between my application's windows which are IE windows)

Yes..I included all possible functions in here... and it works Ok if I have only one IE window!

But when I have 2 IE windows, one of them opened with showModalDialog/showModlessDialog function - it doesn't work.

It looks weird but when I switch from the modal window to its parent, the focus goes from the modal window to the parent but the modal window is still on the top.

Please advise.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's how modal windows work -- they will always display above the parent window when the parent is visible, and there's no way to change this behaviour.

MSDN has more [information on owner windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#owned_windows), specifically it mentions that:

> An owned window is always above its owner in the z-order.

Comment: Ok.. I got it… Then I can use another approach -  to  minimize all modal windows to show the parent. Are there any drawbacks of this approach?

Comment: Or just don't open modal windows if it turns out you really don't want a modal window.  Why are you using modal windows if you want them to behave like non-modal windows?